# Event at app shutdown Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-8.1

I'm creating my first application for my Windows Phone using the camera. And at shutdown I want to call a dispose-method to release resources from a `MediaCapture object`. But I cannot find an event which triggers when the application shuts down.

Does anyone know how I can dispose this object at shutdown? Cause when closing the application now makes my phone freeze.

Comment: Are you targeting *Silverlight* or *Runtime*?

Comment: @Romasz Haha I'm not sure actually... How do I check what I'm targeting?

Comment: For example in *Solution Explorer* window you can see beside your project name *Windows Phone 8.1* or *Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1*. Also your `MainPage` will be of type `Page` in *WinRT* and `PhoneApplicationPage` in *Silverlight*. When you choose new project you can select *Blank App* or *Blank App (Silverlight)* - the second should be in the templates somewhere below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your app.xaml.cs you normally got this class

```
    public sealed partial class App : Application
```

Inside you got two interresting methods already there when you create the project

```
protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
{
   // some code here
   // will run when app launch
}
```

And this one

```
/// <summary>
/// Invoked when application execution is being suspended.  Application state is saved
/// without knowing whether the application will be terminated or resumed with the contents
/// of memory still intact.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender">The source of the suspend request.</param>
/// <param name="e">Details about the suspend request.</param>
private void OnSuspending(object sender, SuspendingEventArgs e)
{
   // some code here
}
```

So as you can read in the summary that explains the function, it is called when user suspend the application, but you don't know if the application will terminate or be resumed later, and I think you don't have a way to differentiate.

So I would suggest dispose your ressources inside the OnSuspending function

That is for Windows Phone 8.1 and Windows 8.1 metro style application

If you want to do that in a WPF project, you actually got an

```
OnExit(ExitEventArgs e)
```

see Msdn documentation here (for WPF only)

[Msdn OnExit documentation page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.onexit(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I had a hunch you'd have to use this method, but I wanted to be sure. Thank you for the help, my phone is no longer freezing since I now can correctly dispose. Thank you very much